# How to get the sessions in reactjs with axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, session, session-cookies

I am using react.js and Axios. For backend I am using express-sessions. In the login function, if the user successfully login, I set the `res.session.userId` with the relevant value (userId), and sent to frontend the userId.

```
/**
             *  If the credentials are correct and the user is accepted and not banned, set the session with the 
             *  user's id and send status 200 (success)
            */
            if (matchPassword && userRequested.accepted && userRequested.banned == false) {
                req.session.userId = userRequested.userId;
                return res.status(200).send({ userId:userRequested.userId });
            }
```

The frontend, receive the session in the Cookie tab. However, the goal is to get the data from the session and use the data to redirect the user to profile page if it is authenticated and the session is not expired ... I need to get the userId from the cookie storage. I tried 'js-cookie', 'react-cookies'... But none of them works.
I also tried `document.cookie` but get undefined.
[image]

For the Axios configuration I used based URL and credentials mode to be set to true.

```
const FETCH_DATA = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api',
    withCredentials: true
});



export const loginUser = async (email, password) => {
    const user = await FETCH_DATA.post('/login', {email, password});
    console.log(user.status);
    return user;
}
```

I need to get the userId from the session, but to be used on the frontend. So far I am get only in the browser but I am unable to work with it.
[image]

The session from the mysql table looks like this after the user loggedin:
`{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":86400000,"expires":"2022-10-31T09:36:49.418Z","secure":false,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"userId":34}`

Comment: You should either use session or rest api, not both. React goes with rest API, not session. This is a httponly cookie and you can't access it from the frontend

Comment: so the server should stick to session while the frontend will store userId to sessionstorage or localstorage?

Comment: aaa. I understand. Thank you. Spend two days to make the backend :))